# How can I use Facebook as an OpenID provider?

Tags: facebook, openid

I'd like to use my Facebook account for my OpenID accounts. How can I do this?

Comment: Just make a Facebook account? I thought other sites would just offer it if they can, you can't really force them can you?

Comment: Its not one of the options on the different OpenID pages, but I've seen sites that let you use Facebook, Twitter, etc to log in.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Facebook uses OAuth, while Google, Yahoo, AOL, and MySpace use OpenID.

For sites that only accept OpenID, you won't be able to use Facebook.  Many sites accept both OpenID as well as Facebook, Twitter, LinkedIn, Windows LiveID, etc., that are other non-OpenID solutions.

If you're looking to add support for all these ID systems on your website, you might want to check out [Janrain's Engage](http://janrain.com/products/engage/).

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, Facebook allows you to log in to it using another provider's OpenID account, but doesn't actually create an OpenID account for you to log in to other sites. Does that make sense?

See [this Facebook Developer Blog Post](http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/246) for some more information.

Answer (score 1):

Facebook is an OpenID Consumer.

- You can use identities from other OpenID providers like Google email to log in to Facebook

Facebook is not an OpenID Provider.

- You cannot use Facebook identity to log in to sites that consume OpenID

Basically Facebook exposes OAuth, not OpenID.